# How do you get generated HTML from the Windows Phone WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

Before you jump all over me, I know about the SaveToString() method!  The problem is that it only grabs the server-returned HTML.  If it's further processed through script, I don't see a way to get at the actual rendered HTML.  An easy example is a Tumblr page.  If you view the SaveToString source on the phone you get a minimal link to the RSS feed and few other tags.  Try to view the source in IE or Chrome and you'll see the full (and long) HTML.  Any scripting call would replace the HTML, and there don't seem to be any other relevant methods.  Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Could you post an example URL?

Answer (score 0):

Had a look into Javascript?

[Calling JavaScript Functions in WP7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/08/26/calling-javascript-functions-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)

should do you just fine